# Puppet task run throwing invalid json error

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

My Puppet sever is PE 2017.3.1
My Agent node is on 5.5 version

I am facing an error while executing the command
    /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet-task run sample --nodes puppet-agent

My Sample file is a bash file which contains : -

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hostnamectl
```

I was able to list my task using cli

The above puppet-task command throws an error on command line: -

**1. Starting Job 

 2. Invalid Json**

Comment: What does your task json metadata look like? Does it exist?

Comment: No, under ./tasks only init.sh exist

Comment: What is the name of the puppet module that contains the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppet access login token expired. So after recreating it, I was able to perform the task.